# org.hibernate.MappingException seems happens for no reason

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

What am I doing wrong? Exceprion says I need to make "id" field not insertable and not updatable. But I already have those annotations. And I even removed setter method for "id", but it had no effect. Is something missing?

```
weblogic.application.ModuleException: org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: com.shop.database.entities.Object column: OBJECT_ID (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false"):org.hibernate.MappingException:Repeated column in mapping for entity: com.shop.database.entities.Object column: OBJECT_ID (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.checkColumnDuplication(PersistentClass.java:696)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.checkPropertyColumnDuplication(PersistentClass.java:718)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.checkColumnDuplication(PersistentClass.java:740)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.validate(PersistentClass.java:493)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass.validate(RootClass.java:270)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

My Object.class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "LAB3_OBJECTS")
public class Object {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "OBJECT_ID", length = 10, insertable = false, updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private int id;
    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "OBJECT_TYPE_ID", referencedColumnName = "OBJECT_TYPE_ID")
    private ObjectType objectType;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "OBJECT_ID")
    private Object parent;

public Object() {
}

public Object(String name, ObjectType objectType) {
    this.name = name;
    this.objectType = objectType;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public ObjectType getObjectType() {
    return objectType;
}

public void setObjectType(ObjectType objectType) {
    this.objectType = objectType;
}

public Object getParent() {
    return parent;
}

public void setParent(Object parent) {
    this.parent = parent;
}
```

}

Comment: Don't create your own Object  class. It is very missleading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`OBJECT_ID` is already used as the id column so cannot be used for joining. Use a new column

```
public class MyObject {
    ...
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "PARENT_OBJECT_ID")
    private MyObject parent;
```

Comment: How could I only miss that? Thanx, now I can move on.